# COM-порты в Delphi

Tags: delphi, com-порт

Кто-нибудь может выложить ресурс, исходник **по работе с COM-портами в делфи**? Хотелось бы увидеть как реализовать передачу файлов через порты.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что спрашивается про литературу программированию но никак не про само программирование

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я помню, обращение к COM портам в Windows идет через те же API, что и через файл (`CreateFile`, `CloseHandle`, `WriteFile` и т.п.). Я когда-то пользовался книгой [Последовательные интерфейсы ПК. Практика программирования](http://www.bhv.ru/books/book.php?id=2732) , в ней исходники в большом количестве и как раз на Delphi (найти в интернете не проблема)

Comment: А диск где скачать с исходниками. Одна книжка хорошо конечно, но с CD-инфой еще лучше

Comment: И кстати спасибо за ответ.

Comment: http://progbook.ru/delphi/587-agurov-posledovatelnye-interfeisy-pk-praktika.html